# MVC - Javascript events on elements in partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I can't seem to get my js event fire successfully on elements that are found in partial views. It probably has something to do with the way the partial views are loaded, so the elements may not be in the DOM when document.ready is fired.

Clicking on the button only hides the element which is found in the main page (menu-panel2).

What approach to this am I missing?

Main Html:

```
<body>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <div id="upper-menu-container">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_Menu");}
  </div>
  <div id="upper-menu-container2">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_Menu");}
  </div>
  <div id="header-wrapper"></div>
  <div id="menu-panel2">
   Hide me - Hide me
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <input type="button" id="testbutton" value="click me" />
    @RenderBody()
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#testbutton").click(function () {
    $("#menu-panel").toggle();
    $("#menu-panel2").toggle();

  });
});
```

Partial View:

```
<div id="menu-panel">
  Hide me
</div>
```

Comment: you call `@{Html.RenderPartial("_Menu");}` twice, so you have duplicate ID's

Comment: ahh... you beat me too it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh... I just found the problem, which was caused by having two identical partialviews, which probably loaded several elements with the identical id to the DOM.

Case closed!

Comment: can you mark your answer as the right answer, please :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this line:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the end of file.

I have some templates that just work like this.